# How can I make F9 with vim-latex work with "\cite{"?

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

I have installed `vim-latex v1.10.0` on `Fedora 28`, using `vim-plug` as follows:

```
Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'
```

<kbd>F9</kbd> does not work with `\cite{`. It works with `\ref{`,  but `n` and `p` cycle through the results of the last search command.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: `:h cite` gives

> "By disabling the setting Tex_UseCiteCompletionVer2 [ls_a_dA],
>   Latex-Suite will also look for .bbl files (if no .bib file is found) or a
>   \begin{thebibliography} environment. However, a filtering of the results
>   (as described above) will not be available."  (latex-suite.txt)

This was exactly my case, since I used `\begin{thebibliography}`. Thus the solution was to add the line `let Tex_UseCiteCompletionVer2=0` in `.vimrc`.